# MySQL/PHP query to reverse relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with the following columns:

```
ID      Units
1       1234,6543,9876
2       1234,6543
3       6543
4       9876
5       0987
```

I would like to reverse the relationship to get an output like this:

```
Unit    IDs
1234    1,2
6543    1,2,3
9876    1,4
0987    5
```

I was wondering if this could be done in a query or some php, without chunking through with explodes etc?

Comment: Have you considered storing the data in normalized fashion instead of reversing the relationship?

Comment: Perhaps you can make use of the IN function?
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: Here's a question, when you say units is "1234,6543,9876", do you mean that's a string, or what?

Comment: @zfus thanks, I've only used flat structures in simple applications, so wasn't sure how to handle that data in a better way. But now I have the terminology I can go learn for myself. I was thinking this must have been handled someway.

Comment: @manchicken yes it's a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using comma-separated lists in SQL is [awkward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574).  This is a denormalized design, and SQL is not well suited to work with data in this format.

I would fetch all the data back into PHP and manipulate it there.

```
$id_per_unit = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $unit_array = explode(",", $row["Units"]);
  foreach ($unit_array as $unit) {
    $id_per_unit[$unit][] = $row["Id"];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the temporary solution I used, will investigate changing the design to normalized, as per the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT `Unit`, `IDs` FROM `table` ORDER BY `Unit`";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$prev_unit = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    if ($prev_unit != $row['Unit']) {
      // echo a new row with the new unit and then ID
    } else {
      // echo just the ID in the same row, this unit is the same as the last one.
    }
  $prev_unit = $row['Unit'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With only SQL, you can do something like this :

```
SELECT unit , GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM (
    SELECT id,substring_index(Units,',',1) AS unit
    FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT id,REPLACE(
           REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Units,',',2),SUBSTRING_INDEX(Units,',',1),'')
              ,',','') AS unit
    FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT id,REPLACE(
           REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Units,',',3),SUBSTRING_INDEX(Units,',',2),'')
              ,',','') AS unit
    FROM Table1) AS UNITS
WHERE unit != ''
GROUP BY unit
```

See **[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cfdf/26/0)**